# Перебор файла по ключу Python

Tags: python, python-3.10

Написал код по перебору файла по ключу, но функция передает только одну строку, как сделать так, чтобы функция передавала все остальные строки?

```
import json

def executed_operations(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        operations = json.load(file)

    ops = {}
    operation = []
    for i in range(len(operations)):
        if "state" and 'from' not in operations[i]:
            continue
        if operations[i]['state'] == 'EXECUTED':
            date = datetime.strptime(operations[i]['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
            ops['date'] = date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
            ops['description'] = operations[i]['description']
            ops['from'] = operations[i]['from']
            ops['to'] = operations[i]['to']
            ops['operationAmount'] = operations[i]['operationAmount']
            operation.append(ops)
    return operation

x = executed_operations('operations.json')
print(x)
```

Сам файл:

```
[
  {
    "id": 441945886,
    "state": "EXECUTED",
    "date": "2019-08-26T10:50:58.294041",
    "operationAmount": {
      "amount": "31957.58",
      "currency": {
        "name": "руб.",
        "code": "RUB"
      }
    },
    "description": "Перевод организации",
    "from": "Maestro 1596837868705199",
    "to": "Счет 64686473678894779589"
  },
  {
    "id": 41428829,
    "state": "EXECUTED",
    "date": "2019-07-03T18:35:29.512364",
    "operationAmount": {
      "amount": "8221.37",
      "currency": {
        "name": "USD",
        "code": "USD"
      }
    },
    "description": "Перевод организации",
    "from": "MasterCard 7158300734726758",
    "to": "Счет 35383033474447895560"
  },
  {
    "id": 939719570,
    "state": "EXECUTED",
    "date": "2018-06-30T02:08:58.425572",
    "operationAmount": {
      "amount": "9824.07",
      "currency": {
        "name": "USD",
        "code": "USD"
      }
    },
    "description": "Перевод организации",
    "from": "Счет 75106830613657916952",
    "to": "Счет 11776614605963066702"
  },
  {
    "id": 587085106,
    "state": "EXECUTED",
    "date": "2018-03-23T10:45:06.972075",
    "operationAmount": {
      "amount": "48223.05",
      "currency": {
        "name": "руб.",
        "code": "RUB"
      }
    },
    "description": "Открытие вклада",
    "to": "Счет 41421565395219882431"
  },
  {
    "id": 142264268,
    "state": "EXECUTED",
    "date": "2019-04-04T23:20:05.206878",
    "operationAmount": {
      "amount": "79114.93",
      "currency": {
        "name": "USD",
        "code": "USD"
      }
    },
    "description": "Перевод со счета на счет",
    "from": "Счет 19708645243227258542",
    "to": "Счет 75651667383060284188"
  },
  {
    "id": 873106923,
    "state": "EXECUTED",
    "date": "2019-03-23T01:09:46.296404",
    "operationAmount": {
      "amount": "43318.34",
      "currency": {
        "name": "руб.",
        "code": "RUB"
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: `"state" and 'from' not in operations[i]` работает не так как вы думаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    operations = json.load(file)
operation = []
for oper in operations:
    if not (oper.get('from') and oper.get('state')):
        continue
    if oper['state'] == 'EXECUTED':
        date = datetime.strptime(oper['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        date = date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
        operation.append({'date': date,
                          'description': oper['description'],
                          'from': oper['from'],
                          'to': oper['to'],
                          'operationAmount': oper['operationAmount']
                          })

print(operation)
```